# What are the options to export a audio file with speed and pitch changed?

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to make an Android app that simply play and exports audio files with the speed and pitch chosen by the user.

Since API level 23 MediaPlayer gives you PlaybackParams and this is enough for playing. But what are the options for saving this "edited" files? Ideally supporting the same formats that MediaPlayer does.